# xCode force xib to scale per device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

So I am still pretty new to ios programming but I am trying to convert an XIB based application that was designed for ipad, so that it can work on iphone. I wanted to create a universal app view http://www.appcoda.com/ios-univeral-app-tutorial/ however this only works with storyboards as far as I can tell. So what is the easiest way to do this? covert all existing XIB (about 30) to storyboards? or is there any easier way. I simply want the iphone version to look EXACTLY the same as the ipad version. Right now it is giant and looks terrible, you can only see the top left third of the app.

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14718973/1806873). maybe do that for every view if it's an iphone

Comment: Interesting would that have to be applied to all elements within a view (like it seemed he did) or would it just be once for each view?

Comment: I think it'll be once for a view